# Issue in excluding nunit test fixtures from parallel execution

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, testing, nunit, execution

AssemblyInfo.cs

```
using NUnit.Framework;
[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
[assembly: LevelOfParallelism(3)]
```

Now I have 55 test classes in my suite, and I have marked only 5 test class as [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]. When I try to execute the tests from any test class its running parallelly. I need only the 5 test class to run in parallel and other 50 test class should run sequentially.

I tried adding [NonParallelizable] in remaining test class but it didn't help. Any solution or suggestion is welcome..

Nunit version is 3.13.3

Comment: Have you tried adding the Parallelizable attribute to all the relevant tests, and removing it from AssemblyInfo.cs?

Comment: It didn't work, basically it takes the parallelizable definition given in assembly level.  if [assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)] is given in suite then all test classes are running in parallel. If [assembly: NonParrallelizable] is given then it executed the test class sequentially. Attributes given in test class level is not considered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

[assembly: LevelOfParallelism(3)]
namespace YourProject.YourFolder
{
    [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
    public class YourClass
    {

    }
}
```

Change the scope as needed according to your specific solution. I would suggest using `ParallelScope.Children` if you have all the test that you want to run in parallel in the same class.

Comment: This doesn't work for me as I have a single solution.

Comment: Ok, I notice that the TestFixtureSource is causing the problem. When I remove the TestFixtureSource from test classes it's working fine as expected. Is there any way I can have parallel and non parallel test classes both using TestFixtureSource

Answer (score 0):

I think you set [assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)] globally for your assembly, so all tests will be executed in parallel in your assembly.

Easiest way for "turning on" parallel execution is creating .runsettings file with "nunit config" and using Parallelizable attribute with specific ParallelScope for your test method or class in code for example [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)].

```
<RunSettings>
   <NUnit>
       <NumberOfTestWorkers>2</NumberOfTestWorkers>
   </NUnit>
</RunSettings>
```

In your case you should add [Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)] attribute for class which requires parallel fixtures execution, other classes without this attribute will not run in parallel.

Comment: I tried and this doesn't work, picking the tests sequentially.

Comment: Please delete AssemblyInfo.cs and these annotations [assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)], [assembly: LevelOfParallelism(3)]. Add settings.runsettings and in your VS you have to load your runsettings file in Test -> Configure Run Settings -> Select runsettings file

Comment: Ok I have tested it on 3.12.0 NUnit version and it works. I found this issue also https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/3735 for versions lower than 3.12.0 it probably doesn't work.

Comment: Yupe, latest NUnit version and 3.12.0 works. Thanks